# SQLitedb implementation for android messaging

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am developing a messaging app in Android. When I send a message, I store the message in `sqlite db` with `insert()`. I store it as an object containing sender,receiver,message.

Now when my Fragment is created in `onCreateView()`, I restore it using `get`. The problem is I dont know how to implement this `get` for my example. Here is my code.

In my `Fragment` ,

```
public void sendTextMessage(View v) {
        String message = msg_edittext.getEditableText().toString();
        ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(message,true);
        chatMessage.body = message;
        Log.d("hi","Inside3");
            localstoragehandler.insert("me", "receiver", chatMessage.body.toString());
            msg_edittext.setText("");
            chatAdapter.add(chatMessage);
            chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         }

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    localstoragehandler = new LocalStorageHandler(getActivity());
    dbCursor = localstoragehandler.get("receiver", "me");
        Log.d("hi","Store0");
        if (dbCursor.getCount() > 0){
            Log.d("hi","Store1");
            int noOfScorer = 0;
            dbCursor.moveToFirst();
            while ((!dbCursor.isAfterLast())&&noOfScorer<dbCursor.getCount())
            {
                Log.d("hi","Store2" + dbCursor.getString(3));
                noOfScorer++;
                chatAdapter.addmsg(dbCursor.getString(3));
                dbCursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        localstoragehandler.close();
    }
```

When my fragment is created I only get the last message sent. This means - 
For example I sent -

```
Hi
How
Are 
You
```

When the fragment is created , I get it as -

```
   You
   You
   You
   You
```

Here is my `chatAdapter` method -

```
public void add(ChatMessage object) {
        chatMessageList.add(object);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addmsg(ChatMessage msg) {
        Log.d("hi","Store3" + msg);
        chatMessageList.add(msg);
        Log.d("hi","Store4" + chatMessageList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        chatMessageList.clear();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(message,true);`
outsite the function?
Crreating new instance can help, as it helped me before!

```
ChatMessage chatmessage;
public void sendTextMessage(View v) {
chatmessage = new Chatmessage(....)
//.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy but sloppy fix would be to remove the while loop and only get the first result seen how you're retrieving the correct result multiple times.
I can't help you further than that without seeing what your "get" mthod is actually doing.